# Changing initial view Controller depending on iPhone screen size

Tags: ios

I want to know if is it possible to change the initial view Controller depending on the device screen size.
In my app I need to set some buttons on fixed positions over a background image, and therefore I need that depending on the screen size (iPhone 4 or iPhone 5) the app launches one initial viewController, configured to fit the iPhone 4 screen size, or another viewController, configured to fit the iPhone 5 screen size.

I am using story Board.

Thank you.

UPDATED.

I am including the background image, inside the white circles I want to add buttons. As it is now, if I put the buttons using the storyBoard, they don't coincide at both screen sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is that it's not good to do that, use 1 viewController that can fit it's self in any screen size using AutoLayout or using springs and struts.

It's also good chance to learn AutoLayout because its very important
Check [Raywenderlich Tutorial about Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Comment: Thank you, I will check the tutorial and try using your advice.

Comment: But if for some reason you needed to do this then its straigtforward to programatically load whatever view controller you want and set it as the rvc within the application delegate after first checking the screen size.

Comment: Yes you can programmatically change the view controller but if the two are completely different, In this case you make a ViewController for every device size! Thats not good.

Comment: Please, take a look at my updated question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Hossam's answer that autolayout is the way to go since you are using storyboards. One additional use case I can imagine for you however, is if the background images you are using are screen size dependent (iphone 3/4 vs 5/5s).

In which case, in addition to autolayout for the buttons you'll want to go with Logan's answer and check the screen bounds, such that in pseudo-code

if (iphone 5/5s, i.e. bounds size height is 568) {
  use the bigger background 
} else {
  use the alternate smaller background.
}

In other words, you may elect to combine both their answers.

Comment: Please, take a look at my updated question. Thank you

Comment: Another solution might be to get the circles off of the background, and use them as custom buttons--in which case you can then use an autolayout only solution. IF you're stuck with a fixed 3.5" and 4" background, then you may elect to "fork" the storyboard such that you have two viewcontrollers scenes that share the SAME view controller (one for 3.5 and one for 4"). The trick would be setting the navigation flow to detect screen size (for example, in prepareforsegue) on the preceeding view-controller.